# Does Google require re-verification of consent screen when credentials change?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

Specifically, on Google Cloud Platform, does adding `localhost` in web app client's authorized redirect URIs cause re-verification of consent screen to take place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, acccording to the [FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en):

> If you change any of the details that appear on your OAuth consent
> screen, such as the project's icon, display name, homepage or privacy
> policy URL, or authorized domains, you need to have your app
> re-verified for branding prior to updates being published to your
> OAuth consent screen. This brand verification process typically takes
> 2-3 business days.